# Can't plot a chart with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code, and it's supposed to plot me a chart with a number, but it won't work. And I don't get any error

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot

# %matplotlib inline
all_values = data_list[0].split(',')
image_array = numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:]).reshape((28, 28))
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(image_array, cmap='Greys', interpolation='None')
plt.show(image_array, cmap='Greys', interpolation='None')  
scaled_input = (numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.1
print (scaled_input)
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: This is not a [mre] so we can't really help much. If this is the exact code you are running, then you are not even running it because this code produces many errors so I don't think it is fair to blame Pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Your code should not even run:

- `all_values = data_list[0].split(',')` should give `NameError: data_list undefined`
- `plt.show` should give `NameError: plt undefined`
- `plt.show(image_array, cmap='Greys', interpolation='None')` should give `TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'cmap'`

My guess is that your code did not run at all... In PyCharm, you should be able to right click on your script and click on `run script` or something